# Environmental Variables set in Buildspec.yml file not showing in Environment when built (AWS Lambda / CodeStar)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-codestar

First a little bit of background. We are building an application in AWS using CodeStar to control everything. It is being written in Python 3

But despite every attempt we are unable to get the variables we set in the buildspec.yml file to show in the environment when we deploy the code.

For example the following is essentially the buildspec.yml file.

```
    version: 0.2

      env:
        variables:
            PASSWORD: "abc123"

      artifacts:
        type: zip
        files:
          - template-export.yml
          - '**/*'
```

When we then build a function which prints the entirety of the Environment variables MY_VAR does not show in the variables. The code we are using is essentially this:

```
    import os

    def handler(event, context):
      PASSWORD1 = str(os.environ["PASSWORD"])
      print(PASSWORD1)
```

As near as I can tell, it currently has a role assigned to it which gives it full permissions.I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but as of now we haven't been able to find it - despite hours spent trying to get it to work

Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Note - this seems very similar to:

[AWS Lambda is not reading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632576/aws-lambda-is-not-reading-environment-variables?rq=1)

but we are wanting to set the variables in the yaml file and not via the Lambda configuration area

Answer (score 1):

If you have a template.yaml file, put our environment variables in that file. In your Resource's properties include a property called Environment with a sub-property called Variables. Here is a similar example to what we use.

```
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 3
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
```